# Will this existing Outlet Box support a 23 lb ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling-fan

I live in a house that was build in 2015, this outlet currently mounts a light fixture. I want to replace the lights with a ceiling fan but I am not sure if the current outlet box will support the fan. The fan is 23 lbs in weight.

The text printed on the box

Carlon 
4" Ceiling Box
20 CU. IN. VOL
328 CU. CM.

I have taken some picture and shared them at link below.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!Apxt8MAKVTWKi7k1YVtGORzYttrPfA

Comment: It's not about the static weight.  Ceiling fans **vibrate and shake**.  Because of this they need very tough boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like just a plastic ceiling box without any extra support. If that is the case, the answer is no, you would definitely want to replace it with a fan box which you can get in kit form. See the picture. You can find these kits at Lowes for under $20. [image: https://www.lowes.com/pd/RACO-1-Gang-Silver-Steel-Interior-New-Work-Old-Work-Ceiling-Fan-Ceiling-Electrical-Box/3127059?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-RoughPlumbingElectrical-_-ElectricalBoxes-_-3127059:RACO&CAWELAID=&kpid=3127059&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=1559&k_clickID=c8b993d0-4d74-49d9-8be8-51a359aa304a&gclid=CjwKCAjw2MTbBRASEiwAdYIpsaNannm5lgcF2FFAl1YxrmvCOVCLL6LwvRJc2WqaRN44D-s8vq211xoCE4EQAvD_BwE]The nice thing is that it looks like you have a single cable coming in which makes the replacement much easier than if you had splices to take apart and try to get wired back together in the new box.

To get the old one out, it will probably take a hammer and screw driver. Bust it out, pry it out, whatever. Be ready for insulation to possibly fall out and make a mess. The new kit has a brace bar with feet on each end that need to be able to sit flat on the top of the ceiling drywall, lath & plaster, or whatever ceiling material you have. The brace bar expands as you twist it to spread across and wedge itself between the ceiling joists. You have to line it up with the center of the hole. Then the box attaches by way of four screws and a little horse-shoe shaped hanger that mounts over the bar. For a fan you should use the #10 screws. This kit I've shown can support up to 110 pounds.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I will try to replace the the box. Will post back on how it go.

Answer (score 1):

Likely **not**. The junction box appears to be plastic, and from below, I can see no sign of a ceiling fan mounting bracket. There are a number of sites that show how to install a ceiling fan, such as [Loewes.com](https://www.lowes.com/projects/build-and-remodel/install-a-ceiling-fan/project) or [Family Handyman](https://www.familyhandyman.com/electrical/how-to-install-a-ceiling-fan-brace/).