# Will ceiling junction box support fan mounting?

Tags: ceiling-fan, junction-box, support

Will current ceiling junction box support fan? Not exactly sure if a fan was mounted to it prior as I recently moved into this apartment. Somewhat older of an apartment and box doesn’t directly state if fan is supported or not. Figured it was better to check first.
[image]

Comment: I'd change those 2 drywall screws to something less brittle.

Comment: Duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/145104/will-this-existing-outlet-box-support-a-23-lb-ceiling-fan/145105#145105

Comment: Is there a joist behind the box, perchance?

Comment: Do you already have the fan? My experience is with Hunter fans, both the very heavy old ones and the new much lighter ones. If you are installing the latter, the kit comes with *two* purpose designed wood screws which go into a ceiling joist or other sound wood. If you would be installing of of the old heavy fans, you would pry out the center knockout, drill a hole for a single very heavy hook. These would go *through* holes in the metal "pancake" box, or around the box, into the wood joist.  This box itself does not support the weight of the fan.  What kind of fan are you mounting?

Comment: @JimStewart it is a new Hampton Bay Hawkins 44 inch think it is around 15-20lbs. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Hawkins-44-in-Brushed-Nickel-Ceiling-Fan-YG204-BN-D/303007304

Comment: Read the instructions and examine the parts in detail before you start. Determine the thickness of the wood structure above the drywall ceiling. You might have to use the holes currently occupied by the two drywall screws for heavy wood screws (if that is in the parts kit) for the fan bracket. If so, put screws in the open holes (to hold the box to the ceiling) and then remove the drywall screws.  If

Comment: It may be that the fan bracket is designed to *cover* the pancake box and the two heavy screws would be *outside* the box.

Comment: @JimStewart https://imgur.com/a/7FbL9c2

Comment: *Some* ceiling boxes are rated to support a fan with screws/bolts into something that looks like those tabs, but a standard pancake box like you have is not rated for a fan. The threads in the tabs are not rated to hold the weight and vibration of a fan. And if the fan is hung from the box, then the box must be attached to the structure with screws that are rated to hold up the weight of the fan. Certainly drywall screws would not be allowed.

Comment: Your shallow ceiling box (aka "pancake" box) *appears to me* to be just a standard pancake box rated for a light weight fixture, but I could be wrong. If it is rated for a fan, there should be some indication on the box. The parts and instructions for Hunter fans of about the same weight as your fan direct the installer to drive some special wood screws into ceiling joists and not to depend on the existing *standard* box to support the fan. I expect the Hampton Bay fan to have the same setup. Read the instructions carefully.

Comment: @JimStewart Thanks for the help. Will return and just get a light fixture

Comment: (Our internet has been down for almost 12 hours.) The hardware with your fan will allow mounting over your pancake box, but just not directly to the pancake box.

Answer (score 1):

### Mount the fan to the joist or block behind the box, not the box

The two screws in the back of the box in line with the mounting tabs appear to land in a joist or cross-block in the ceiling.  I would attach the fan to that using two 1/4" by 3" structural wood screws (*not* drywall, deck, or lag screws -- look for something with an ICC-ES or IAPMO rating, such as a FastenMaster TimberLok or Simpson Strong-Drive SDS) through the fan bracket and ceiling finish board into the structural member.

Comment: I recently did this for two new fan installs in my house and it worked fine. My fans came with two sets of screws, one set for going into a metal box but the other were long wood screws meant to mount to a stud like this so if your fan kit came with their kind of screw it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It may, but I concur with brhans. Drywall screws are very easy to snap right off and they (at a minimum) should be replaced by even just Deck Screws, which have the shear resistance of nails.

But, as with ANY apartment, call the Landlord and get their written approval and/or have them perform the installation and ALL electrical modifications...as is likely in your contract.